# Unique random number for every class instantiation

Tags: php, class, random, instance

I want to generate a random ID via `rand()`  for every instantiation of my class. And I want it to be unique. Here is what I wrote, but this doesn't work.

```
class Computer
{
    private $id = 0; // placeholder for ID
    private $id_list = []; // placeholder to store used IDs

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->checkID();
    }

    private function checkID()
    {
        $this->id = rand(1,3);
        if (!in_array($this->id, $this->id_list))
        {
            array_push($this->id_list, $this->id);
        } else {
            $this->checkID();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this intentionally with generating low values, like `rand(1,3)`, and I got three objects with IDs 2, 2, 1. So it's not working.

I assume that is because for every new instance of a class `$id_list` array becomes empty. But I've seen people doing almost the same thing. Declaring a `$counter` variable and putting `$this->counter++` in the `__construct` method. So what's the difference?

Comment: `rand` doesn't make unique numbers.

Comment: That is why I wrore a `checkID()` function.

Comment: Have you tried making $id_list static?

Comment: Yeah, tried it a moment ago. Got an error "Accessing static property Computer::$id_list as non static".

Comment: The checkID method has to be static as well.

Comment: With `$id`, `$id_list` and `checkID()` as static it doesn't throw an error anymore, but now it's not assigning any value to `$id`. Something wrong with the logic in `checkID()`?

Comment: Try `random_int()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `$counter` variable used this way is not random, but it is unique. It simply counts the objects as they are created, beginning with 0 or 1 depending on your preference. The difference is that all objects of the class are accessing the same variable. To accomplish that, the variable must be declared as static, like so:

```
public static $counter = 0;

function __construct() 
    self::$counter++;
}
```

To generate a random number that is also unique, you'll have to write a subroutine that compares the generated number to the id of every instantiated object. This could become inefficient very quickly, and I don't recommend it. But if you were going to do it, it could look something like this:

```
class Computer
{
    private $id = 0; // placeholder for ID
    private static $id_list = []; // placeholder to store used IDs

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = self::checkID();
    }

    private static function checkID()
    {
        $newID = rand(1,10000);
        if (!in_array($newID, self::$id_list))
        {
            array_push(self::$id_list, $newID);
            return $newID;
        } else {
            self::checkID();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what about random values? It's not about efficiency, I just want to understand how something like this would work. Also, will something like this be considered more advanced? I've been learning PHP only for a month. Perhaps it'll be too hard for me to understand.

Comment: Sure, the trouble is being able to scale a solution. If you can't predict how many objects you are going to spin up, then you can't accurately set the range for random numbers. And after the number range fills up, then errors shall abound. That's all, just thinking about scalability.

Comment: Well in that case the IDs could be stored in a database and indexed, but that's another matter for another day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make $id_list static so that it keeps the stored values, as such:

```
class Computer
{
    private $id = 0; // placeholder for ID
    private static $id_list = []; // placeholder to store used IDs

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->checkID();
        print_r(self::$id_list);
    }

    private function checkID()
    {
        $this->id = rand(1,3);
        if (!in_array($this->id, self::$id_list))
        {
            array_push(self::$id_list, $this->id);
        } else {
            $this->checkID();
        }
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    new Computer();
}
```

I added the printing lines to showcase the result, but you should get the point.

Comment: Aha, now I see that the problem, after you suggested making `$id_list` static, was that I didn't use `self::` inside the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the [spl_object_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) function:

> This function returns a unique identifier for the object. This id can
>   be used as a hash key for storing objects, or for identifying an
>   object, as long as the object is not destroyed. Once the object is
>   destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects.

You can call [spl_object_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) every time you construct the object:

```
class Computer
{
    private $id = "";            // placeholder for a unique random Id

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = spl_object_hash( $this );
    }
}
```

Note that the uniqueness of the values returned by [spl_object_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) has a 'weak' point:

> Once the object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other
>   objects.

In this case, you could construct you own [hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) mechanism using a code such as this one:

```
class Computer
{
    private $id = "";            // placeholder for a unique random Id
    private static $seed = 0;    //placeholder for the seed

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$seed++;
        $this->id = hash('md5', get_class($this) . self::$seed );
    }
 }
```

Virtually, There is no need to check for duplicated Ids because md5 hashes has a collision probability of 1 in `2^128`!